# Generic AttributeConverter for Enums in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create a Generic class which implements AttributeConverter and can be used in @Converter annotation for all enums.
I have two different enums each one has a converter class but both converter classes are doing same thing.
The following are the code Snippet.

```
public enum Type {
    BASIC(1, "Basic"),
    ADVANCE(2, "Advance");

    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;

    private Type(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Type getType(Integer id) {
        if (id == null) { return null; }
        for (Type type: Type.values()) {
            if (id == type.getId()) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class TypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Type, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Type type) {
        return type.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Type convertToEntityAttribute(Integer databaseValue) {
        return Type.getType(databaseValue);
    }
}



public enum State {
    FIRST(1, "First"),
    SECOND(2, "Second");

    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;

    private State(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static State getState(Integer id) {
        if (id == null) { return null; }
        for (State state: State.values()) {
            if (id == state.getId()) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class StateConverter implements AttributeConverter<State, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(State state) {
        return state.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public State convertToEntityAttribute(Integer databaseValue) {
        return State.getState(databaseValue);
    }
}




@Table(name = "um_user")
public class User
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String username;
    private String password
    
    @Convert(converter = TypeConverter.class)
    private Type type;

    @Convert(converter = StateConverter.class)
    private State state;
}
```

Now I want to create a generic converter that can be used instead of both TypeConverter & StateConverter.

Comment: Hi, Why do you not simply store the Enumeration in your entity? - it will be represented as an integer anyways

Comment: Hello @lucniner, could you please send sample code.

Comment: Take a look at the @Enumerated annotation.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this example](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html)

Comment: Does all your enums going to be having same values as `1, 2` ?

Comment: @Enumerated annotation techniques have few drawbacks.

Comment: @code_mechanic It is not necessary for all enums to have same values. In my actual project I have dozens of enums each one has a different values.

Comment: Then I don't think it would be possible to generalise in such manner and even if possible, I think you should not go for it, it would be unnecessary abstraction and writing boilerplate code is rather easy than maintaining that abstraction, also check if you can use default enum values (starts from 0) then as everyone said you don't need converter.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have tried many times, but the convertToEntityAttribute method is what causes it to be next to impossible without creating an extension to Enum class.